# Reading from stdin and sending with UDP, creating two-way communication

Tags: java, sockets, udp

I have the code below which creates a socket UDP-style. I run and compile the code and it works just fine. If I then use "netcat -u  " I am able to send messages from the client to the server but not the other way around. So what I want and what I have been trying to do is to read from stdin and printing it(all this running in a second thread). Making it a two-way communication. Anyone know what I need to fix? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;

public class NetcatUDP {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];

        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 // Read from stdin and send somehow?
            }
        }.start();

        while (true) {
            socket.receive(packet);
            System.out.println(new String(packet.getData()).trim());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know who you're sending the packet to? What do you want, it to be sent to the last person that sent you a packet? Consider the case when person A sends a packet, then person B sends you a packet. Then you send a packet out, who should the message go to?

Comment: I want it to be sent to the one who opens the connection, assume it's only one client and the server. If the client types "123" the server should receieve "123" and if the server types "321" the client should recieve "321".

Comment: UDP is inherently simplex (single direction). If you want duplex, you have to either create a new DatagramSocket etc, or change protocol (TCP is full duplex).

Comment: @jbm Is it possible to create another DatagramSocket in the new thread and send a message to the client? If you know feel free to share

Comment: "I want it to be sent to the one who opens the connection" but there's no *connection* in UDP, and that's why it is simplex. You need to create another UDP channel (I use the word "channel" to avoid the wrongly assumed "connection"), or use another protocol.

Comment: It sounds a lot like you really just want TCP. What's your reasoning for choosing UDP?

Comment: I don't know, it's a question of goal before being a question of how to  implement that goal. If you want bidirectional communication, then though doable, UDP is not the best protocol in the first place. You must understand the fundamental merits/limitations of both UDP and TCP before chosing to implement with one rather than the other.

Comment: @Cruncher Well, I'm just fooling around and I've managed to do this using TCP but didn't succeed using UDP.

Comment: @jbm Could you help me with the code to create another UDP channel which reads from stdin and sends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP is a connection-less protocol, which means you can send a message to anyone and receive a message from anyone with a single socket.

For the simple example you're using, you can actually use the same program for both endpoints.  Besides reading in the local port number from the command line, read in the remote IP address and port as well.  Then in your thread, you read from stdin using `Console.readLine()`, construct a `DatagramPacket` with the line read from the console, remote IP, and remote port, and send it with the existing `socket` you have.

Comment: @Fjodor What I described should be enough for you to put something together yourself.  If you have a specific question, update your question with the code you have so far.